# Is there extension signing for Google Chrome as there is for Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, google-chrome-extension

Firefox prevents the extension from loading in the browser if any of its files are modified after installation in the profile folder.

Is there extension signing for Google Chrome as there is for Firefox? Can the user or a third-party program manipulate the installed extension from the Chrome Webstore and still have it loaded in Google Chrome?

Comment: Extensions can be modified by installing a copy as unpacked.

Comment: Is not Google Chrome extensions already unpacked when installed from  Chrome WebStore?

Comment: Chrome extension `crx` contains compressed files and a it's signature. So during installation it checks the sign. Also you can sign a sources using chrome built-in `Pack extension`. Or take one of plenty `crx` tool.

Comment: Thanks. OK it downloads as CRX but it is unpacked during installation. Is not folder subject to manipulation? Does that signing protects the folder like it does CRX?

Comment: Chrome stores the checksum of each extension in the protected secure preferences file. Try modifying files of any extension from store and you'll see it's disabled automatically.